# how does random forest's function predict_proba() works?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, predict

I'm working on `python 3.4`, I'm trying to do some prediction using sklearn `random forest` model.
I first generated a `confusion matrix` and computed accuracy as described below:

```
accuracy= confusion_matrix.trace() / len(testing_dataframe)
```

This gave me an accuracy of about `0.18` which is not good enough

So, in order to get a higher result, I generated 6 propositions (I have about 1000 label) using the `predict_proba()` method and computed the accuracy as follows:

```
Boolean_array=np.zeros(len(testing_dataframe))
if label[i] is in propositions[i]:
   Boolean_array[i]= True
else:
   Boolean_array[i]= False

accuracy=numpy.mean(propositions)
```

And this gave me an accuracy of about `0.16` which is quite weird because I'm expecting it to be higher.

This is why I would like to know if `predict()` and `predict_proba()` are related, I mean:

```
predict(X)=predict_proba(X).max()
```

Does any one knows how does `predict_proba` works please and why am I getting lower accuracy?

**Edit:**

Here is a small sample of my data:

features `DataFrame`:

```
    f0              f1          f2        f3       f4             f5              f6       f7        f8             f9       ...        f90        f91       f92         f93         f94         f95         f96          f97        f98        f99
0   0.535271    0.025914    0.562412    -0.419993   0.681204    0.454155    -0.011025   0.038262    0.527357    -0.050546   ...     0.030861    -0.610272   0.317212    -0.418725   0.177978    -0.417070   0.053116    0.395432    0.291500    1.316563
1   -0.901409   -0.516550   -0.332680   1.256825    0.493730    -0.874850   -0.709655   1.452980    -1.383530   0.168827    ...     0.035605    0.445295    -1.631235   0.297015    0.204900    -0.064275   -0.739375   0.583020    -0.949815   1.621750
2   0.160291    0.817350    -0.751626   0.226337    0.727847    0.086183    -0.376025   1.272175    0.031435    0.418815    ...     0.025983    -0.118028   -0.608380   -0.626938   0.212298    -0.948225   0.461030    0.565805    0.860127    1.669100
3   -0.476125   -0.670245   0.146448    0.242735    1.179170    -1.206770   -0.374161   0.474205    0.605703    -0.915345   ...     -0.737470   1.207160    1.749050    1.401800    -0.694545   0.621000    0.133150    0.117960    -0.712190   -0.829515
4   1.592632    0.406484    -0.582462   -0.273904   -0.043725   0.473370    -0.561084   -0.586366   0.395254    -0.137352   ...     -1.805612   -1.325500   -0.304604   0.031349    1.496978    -0.026860   0.023190    1.226166    1.279988    1.158928
```

Labels `DataFrame`:

```
0    1360
1     268
2     269
3    1047
4    1344
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: assuming X is one sample,  predict(X) gives highest vote count from classification using different decision trees used inside the random forest, predict_proba gives weighting for all the trees.  max() might be same for one sample X but watch out when you take more samples at once.

Comment: @suvy In fact, I'm taking 10000 at once and put them in a list like this `[array([proba1, proba2....]), array([proba1, proba2....]), ...]` and I iterate over this list and take the max() of each element.

Comment: hard to tell anything more without the data, can you post a sample portion of data.

Comment: @suvy Done, I added some samples of my data

Comment: that doesnt help much, no one can try a method with your data pasted. it would also help to put in what have you tried or your script.

Comment: @suvy What are you talking about? `pandas.read_clipboard`.

Comment: @arya McCarthy , how are you going to try a random forest classifier with 5 rows of data and still make answer relevant to the OP?

Comment: In the definition of `Boolean_array`, don't you want a loop?